# npm script working in npm 6 is failing in npm 7

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, json-server

I'm working on a windows machine and I have the following npm script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/json-server --static . data.json -m middleware.js --config json-server.json"
  },
```

This works perfectly fine with npm version 6.15.14.

After an update to npm 7.24.1 first it throws this error:

```
./node_modules/.bin/json-server --static . data.json -m middleware.js --config json-server.json

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

After some search I understood that I need to add node in front of the command, which gets me to the next error:

```
C:\Projects\testing-lists\node_modules\.bin\json-server:2
    basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")    
              ^^^^^^^
    
    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

After searching and reading I understood that this is not gonna work on windows, and I changed the script to a simpler version that works fine.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "json-server data.json"
  },
```

**My question is, why this differences between NPM 6 and NPM 7 - what changed so much? Or what would be the explanation for the first version of the command working in NPM 6.**
Thanks!